# Is there a way to avoid the repetition of similar patterns in regex?

Tags: regex

I use vscode and installed an extension that hides comments. Writing in Python I want to hide triple-quote docstrings (**"""strings"""**), which are not technically comments, but are often used like that, and even when they are not comments, they can clutter the code in a similar way. Luckily, this extension allows me to hide additional lines using regex, but regex has been a difficult topic for me for a while...

Since it's something that comes from an extension and not my own code, **I don't know the "regex dialect" or programming language**. And **I cannot modify the code** to have ifs, elifs, modules or whatever.

#### *Any variable, any logical flow, must come from the one (singular, apparently) regex expression.*

To match:

```
"""This is a long Python ""docstring"" that sometimes is used as a
comment. It can include newlines without using "\\n", although it
will print "\\n" as a newline."""
```

What I'd need is:

```
^(tabs or spaces)(three single or double quotes)(whatever, including up to two
consecutive quotes of the type previously matched)(three quotes of the type
previously matched)
```

From now I have:

```
(^(tabs or spaces)(three double quotes)(whatever, including up to two consecutive
double quotes)(three double quotes)) OR (^(tabs or spaces)(three single quotes) 
(whatever,including up to two consecutive single quotes)(three single quotes))
```

Actual code **(inside User\settings.json)**:

```
"regex": "(^(\\s)*([\"]{3,3})(([^\"][\"]{1,2}[^\"])|[^\"])*([\"]{3,3}))|
(^(\\s)*([']{3,3})(([^'][']{1,2}[^'])|[^'])*([']{3,3}))

"flags": ""
```

Which works, but it's ugly and has unnecessary repetitions. Regex it's not famous for having pretty code, but I think it can be done better. I've read in the Python documentation of regex (which isn't necessarily applicable to this extension, since I don't know the programming language of the extension) something about "substrings accesible by name" which makes me think that there could be some variable-like behaviour available in regex, but sometimes the documentation can be a bit cryptic for newbies and I don't really find my answer there, so my question is:

Is there a way to avoid this kind of repetition in regex?

Edit: From what I've heard, that @InSync also mentioned, the programming language is **likely Javascript or Typescript**

Comment: To match the same thing as something previously matched, use a capture group and back-reference.  See https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Comment: What extension is this? If it's for VSCode, then possibly it is written in JS/TS and therefore doesn't use Python's regex engine.

Comment: @InSync , It's "Hide comments" by Elio Struyf. Yep, I thought the same, but since I didn't know which programming language it was, Python docs were as good as any other documentation XDDD

Comment: @CarySwoveland Done! :D. My intention is to hide it completely, so the regex expression should match all of it.

Comment: Carlos, this question was closed on the grounds that it is a duplicate of an earlier question. Did you find the answers to the earlier question answered your question satisfactorily?

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, the solution has groups made with Python methods and I cannot write Python code for this. It's not my program. I'm only "allowed" to input the regex expression and the flags. I've submitted it for review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `"regex": "\\s*(['\"]{3})(.|\\n)+?(\\1)\\s*"`

Not sure which plugin and regex dialect you are using. The above JSON-compatible expression is base on the pythonic expression shown in the first example below.

```
import re

doc_str = '''
def mock_func(s: str) -> None:
    """
    Mocked \'\'\'documentation\'\'\'
    
    Args:
        s: mocked parameter
    """
    pass
'''

# Pythonic style with raw-string expression and re.DOTALL
pattern_str = r"""\s*(['"]{3}).+?(\1)\s*"""
patt = re.compile(pattern_str, flags=re.DOTALL)

# JSON equivalent without raw-string and re.DOTALL
# pattern_str = "\\s*(['\"]{3})(.|\\n)+?(\\1)\\s*"
# patt = re.compile(pattern_str)

if match_obj := patt.search(doc_str):
    print(match_obj.group(0))
```

Both should match

```
    """
    Mocked '''documentation'''
    
    Args:
        s: mocked parameter
    """
```

Note the non-greedy match (`.+?`) to capture everything between the docstring quotes, and that the inner triple quotes are correctly seen as plain text. Leading and trailing spaces are also included.

Comment: For some reason the JSON equivalent didn't work, but substituting, `\\n` with `\\s` it works perfectly. Thanks :D

Comment: @CarlosGonzález it could depend on the regex dialect to resemble `re.DOTALL`. But it doesn't matter now. Glad to hear that it worked!